# Is my Windows 7 primary and secondary DNS setting correct?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I use a Windows 7 desktop PC with a TP Link Wireless N ADSL2 + Modem Router.

My PC is connected to the TP Link via a LAN cable while another 2 PCs of my secretaries are connected via WiFi.

I am not good at networking. I wonder if my primary and secondary settings are correct.

I can see there are 2 places to set the pri and sec DNS: 1) in Windows adapter setting IPv4, 2) in TP Link's control panel. And I don't understand why there are two places to make the settings.

Since I am not sure what to do, I have posted the screenshots of the settings and also the test results of Namebench and DNS Jumper.

Hopefully someone can tell me:

1) What pri and sec DNS values should I use under TP Link's control panel?

2) What pri and sec DNS values should I use uner Windows' IPv4 configuration?

3) Should I use the value 192.168.1.1 as it seems like my local LAN IP address.

See screenshot at:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be 4 DNS IP addresses on your router, but in two different places.  2 that the router actually uses, and 2 that it passes out via DHCP (how you get an IP address from the router).

The two DNS IP addresses for DHCP on your router are there so that it can pass those along to the clients that connect to the router and get a DHCP address.  You can change your IP settings to obtain the DNS servers automatically and you will get the DNS servers set on your router.  You can confirm by running ipconfig /all.

1. I would set the DNS of your router and DHCP config to use OpenDNS or Google (8.8.4.4).  It seems like the current setup would work fine.
2. I would set your windows computer to pull them automatically from the router.
3. Yes 192.168.1.1 is the IP of your router.  If you use that as DNS, the router is just passing the request on to whatever you have setup as it's DNS servers (#1).

Comment: Very useful info to me, thanks! Now I set my router's primary DNS to 203.144.207.29 (as it seems fastest http://i.stack.imgur.com/zEcPA.jpg and hosted in Thailand, my country) and secondary DNS to 8.8.4.4. I also changed to AUTOMATICALLY OBTAIN in my PC's IPv4 config. When I run ipconfig /all, it shows DNS server = 192.168.1.1. I hope this is correct. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW, when I run ipconfig /all, it only show DNS server = 192.168.1.1 and it shows nothing about 203.144.207.29 or 8.8.4.4. Is that correct?

Comment: That is probably the way it is setup and will work.  However, for the most reliable connection, you should set the router to pass a secondary dns server.  That setting is probably somewhere under the advanced config.  I would set it to pass out the primary of your router (203.144.207.29) as the secondary for the clients.

Comment: Thanks. But not sure what to do. Can't find anything similar to what you said.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/788039/weird-phenomenon-about-my-pcs-primary-secondary-dns-speed

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are correct, but you might want to change the DNS on the computers to automaticaly obtain the DNS from the router.
This can prevent the computer dropping out of the network some times.
I had it my self, my pc deadlocking the internet because of a preset DNS.
The one on the router you should not change, because this is given to you by your ISP.
It's not the standard format, but this is the server your ISP uses for your DNS connection.
If there is any problem after you try a different configuration, you might want to revert to your old settings.
It may be good to note them down, this makes backtraking later easier.
Hope it will work for you.

Roy

Comment: Your settings are correct, but you might want to change the DNS on the computers to automaticaly obtain the DNS from the router.

### I find your explanation above useful. But should I use the value 192.168.1.1 as the primary DNS for my router. It seems that this value is my router's local IP.

### The values you see are not provided by my ISP. The original setting was AUTOMATICALLY OBTAIN. I use Namebench but it kept asking me to use 192.168.1.1 which I really doubt.

Comment: I wonder if you can look at my post here, please?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/788039/weird-phenomenon-about-my-pcs-primary-secondary-dns-speed