# Weird phenomenon about my PC's primary & secondary DNS speed

Tags: networking, performance, dns

I use DNS Jumper to test the speed of various DNS and this is the result:

## (A) Currently Using

Primary: 203.144.207.29 (39 ms)

Secondary: 8.8.4.4 (71 ms)

## (B) US Open DNS

Primary: 208.67.220.220 (315 ms)

Secondary: 208.67.222.222 (307 ms)

Theoretically I should stick to setting (A) as they are faster.

But when I use setting (A), access to **www.taobao.com** *(a shopping site in mainland China)* is extremely slow although still accessible. For other sites around the world they are fast.

I repeated my test many times and it seems that setting (B) is much faster ONLY for www.taobao.com .

I cannot understand this. Why is setting (B) faster than (A) when both DNS servers are not down. Isn't DNS just address-lookup? Why setting (B) gives me faster download when the DNS speed test is much slower?

Comment: There are other DNS servers besides these that might needs to be queried, unless the DNS server has cached the result due to a previous query and the cache entry hasn't expired. These other DNS servers could be the cause.

Comment: Lawrence, where are you located?  I agree with @Steve that there are a multitude of reasons you can get different results from different DNS servers.  Caching is a big reason.  For instance to really do a good test to compare those different DNS servers you would need to wait until all DNS servers (and your computer, and your router) have dropped it from their cache.

Comment: Thanks.

I am located in south Thailand.

Today I can access www.taobao.com (China) quite fast using setting (A).

Thanks for explaining. I just want to know the theory behind the unusual phenomenon.